# Getting error when using concat when I try to add a space?

Tags: sql, oracle, format, concatenation

I am just traying to combine the owner first and last name into one column and I had that working like this>

```
select 
  dog_name, dog_breed, dog_gender, dog_age, dog_weight,
  concat(own_first_name,' ', own_last_name) as own_name 
from dog join owner on dog.own_num = owner.own_num 
order by dog.dog_breed ASC;
```

But the problem was that there was no space between the names, so I did a lot of research and found that his would be the best way to do it>

```
select dog_name, dog_breed, dog_gender, dog_age, dog_weight, 
  concat(own_first_name, own_last_name) as own_name 
from dog join owner on dog.own_num = owner.own_num 
order by dog.dog_breed ASC;
```

When I do that, I get this>

```
ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
00909. 00000 -  "invalid number of arguments"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 185 Column: 62
```

Comment: You are using Oracle and not MySql. Oracle's concat() does not support more than 2 arguments. Use `||` operator.

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output in your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Oracle:

```
select dog_name, dog_breed, dog_gender, dog_age, dog_weight, RTRIM(own_first_name)||' '|| RTRIM(own_last_name) AS own_name
```

SQL server:

```
select dog_name, dog_breed, dog_gender, dog_age, dog_weight, RTRIM(own_first_name)+' '+ RTRIM(own_last_name) AS own_name
```

Acess:

```
select dog_name, dog_breed, dog_gender, dog_age, dog_weight, own_first_name&' '&own_last_name AS own_name
```

If you need more details a quick search for concatenating columns should help.